# How to create multiple environment-specific cdk pipelines from a cdk pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I use trunk-based development to provision aws resources to different environments according to the branches(develop-> dev, release-> prod). Also, I have separated my application code in three different repositories(infra, backend, UI). So I would need multiple pipelines for these deployments to multiple accounts. I am using a cdk-pipeline repository to create these multiple pipelines but having a problem in instantiating these pipelines with empty stacks. A cdk pipeline expects a stage with stacks while calling `pipeline.addStage()`. How do I include the infra code inside this stage when it exists in a different repository?

Comment: Consider following the best practices and keeping the infra code in the same repository as the app code, it will simplify deployment a lot.

Comment: @gshpychka keeping the complete code of a big application in a single repository is not a best practice.

Comment: Keeping the infra code together with the app code is indeed the best practice advised by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

When using cdk codepipeline you can reference a GitHub repository as the source, an example can be found here: [aws_codepipeline_actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#github)